# Запись в файл

Tags: c++

Привет HashCode.Ru.

Вот код, но я не знаю, как сделать, чтобы при запуске программы создавался файл, ну а в программе вписать что-то и в том файле то, что писали, появится?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    ofstream fout("data_types.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc);

    if (!fout.is_open()) // если файл не был открыт 
    {
        cout << "Файл не может быть открыт или создан\n";
        return 1;
    }

    getchar();

    fout.close();
    cout << "Данные успешно записаны в файл data_types.txt\n";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: > `system("pause");`

Ой.

Comment: @drdaeman, и что же в этом плохого?

Comment: Начнем с того, что это бесполезный костыль. MSVS, если выставлено subsystem console и запущено без отладки, [само спросит перед закрытием](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1775870/116546) окна. А закончим тем, что `cin.get()`, вместо запуска отдельного процесса интерпретатора и `pause` в нем, никто не отменял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если "что-то", то после проверки открытия файла можно вписать

```
string chto_to;
getline (cin, chto_to);
fout << chto_to << endl;
```